# Clear nginx cache via HTTP request?

Tags: nginx, cache

I have the usual

```
    proxy_cache_path        /data/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=drupal:16m;
    proxy_cache_key         "$scheme$host$request_uri";
```

to establish proxy caching. How should I configure nginx to allow deleting a specific item from the cache via an HTTP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do selective page purging on **Drupal** then I would recommend you to read this article since it is long a bit.

To summarize the main steps here:

1. Make sure you have ngx_cache_purge module installed on your Nginx server.
2. Also install php-curl module (php5-curl for Debian/Ubuntu) must be installed on your server.
3. Define your cache for use through the fastcgi cache path
4. Alter the server location that handles our Drupal requests with the following code:

   ```
   location = /index.php {
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/$host/drupal/index.php;
       fastcgi_hide_header X-Drupal-Cache; #optional
       fastcgi_hide_header Etag; #optional
       fastcgi_pass php;

       # Cache Settings
       set $nocache "";
       if ($http_cookie ~ SESS) { #logged in users should bypass the cache
         set $nocache "Y";
       }
       if ($request_uri ~ \? ) { # Purge doesn't handle query strings yet
         set $nocache "Y";
       }
       fastcgi_cache mycache;
       fastcgi_cache_key $host$request_uri;
       fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 1d;
       fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
       fastcgi_cache_bypass $nocache;
       fastcgi_no_cache $nocache;
       add_header X-nginx-Cache $upstream_cache_status; #optional
       expires epoch;
   }
   ```
5. Create a new server listening on a random port on the localhost interface.
6. Enable the Purge and Expire modules and set the proxy URL at admin/settings/purge to `"http://127.0.0.1:8888"`.

and your are done!!

The source of the article: [nginx caching with selective page purging](https://groups.drupal.org/node/125094)